# Flaticon render differently on local and live server

Tags: css, icons

My flaticon.css document that set the gmail icon  :

```
.flaticon-share:before { 
  content: "\f10b"; 
  color: #821571;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 43px;
}
```

In my html :

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="media">
    <div class="media-left">
      <i class="flaticon-share" style="display: inline;"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      <p class="media-heading"><strong>cs@kirimundangan.com</strong></p>
      <a href="mailto:cs@kirimundangan.com" target="_blank">
        <button id="template" class="btn btn-download btn-md">Kirim Lampiran</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works fine on localhost, but on live server, the icon is 200px instead of 43px. Does anyone knows why?

You can visit [here](https://kirimundangan.com) and scroll down.

[image: live server]

This image is on localhost (which I expected) :

[image: localhost]

Comment: It works well when I try the provided link from my macOS/Safari and macOS/Chrome browsers

Comment: I suggest to check the browser error console. Are all the resource files found during the page load?

Comment: no error :( @Jaime

Comment: is the icon showed exactly like the last picture in my question? @Jaime

Comment: yes, it does render the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED. By adding css version in html.

`<link href="<?php echo base_url('asset/css/freelancer.css?v=1') ?>" rel="stylesheet">`

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('asset/icon/font/flaticon.css?v=1') ?>">`